# FizzBuzz help to print all solutions for numbers between 1 and declared n

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner. Working on FizzBuzz in C#. I need the code to print the solution for each number between 1 and the declared n.

- if the number is divisible by 3 then print “fizz”
- if the number is divisible by 5 then print “buzz”
- if the number is divisible by both 5 and 3 then print “fizzbuzz”
- otherwise just print the number itself

I wrote the code like that using the for loop but it doesn't correctly print all the solutions (from 1 to n). Will appreciate some guidance.

```
class Result
{

    public static void fizzBuzz(int n)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {

            if (n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FizzBuzz");
                

            }
            else if (n % 3 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fizz");
                

            }
            else if (n % 5 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Buzz");
                

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n);
                

            }
        }

    }

}

class Solution
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());

        Result.fizzBuzz(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What does your program output instead?

Comment: After entering for example 5 it prints
5
Buzz
Buzz
Buzz
Buzz

After entering 7 it prints
7
7
7
7
7
7
7

Comment: Look at the `if` statements inside your `for` loop. You're checking against the value of `n`. Does `n` ever change?

Comment: I dont understand. Shouldn't the loop go all the way, come back, then increment i by 1 and go until i is equal to n? I just don't see what I'm missing here.

Comment: Exactly! Now look at your `if` statement. Are you using `i`?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `n` with `i` inside the loop in your `fizzBuzz` method:

```
using System;

class Solution {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.Write("Enter n: ");
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());
        Result.fizzBuzz(n);
    }
}

class Result {
    public static void fizzBuzz(int n) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {  // Alternatively just i % 15 == 0
                Console.WriteLine("FizzBuzz");
            } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
                Console.WriteLine("Fizz");
            } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                Console.WriteLine("Buzz");
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
Enter n: 20
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
14
FizzBuzz
16
17
Fizz
19
Buzz
```

Comment: Omg thank you! Ok now I see where the problem was! Thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem happy to help. #RoadTo15KThenAFK